# Block Search Engines from Indexing "edited history" of questions

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, search-indexing

I had some spare time, and found out that Google actually indexes the "edited history" of a question. I think you guys should add the "edited history" as one of the pages that robots from search engines should not index. "Suggested edits" are not indexed, and these shouldn't be either. Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [robots.txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) already tells search engines to not index the revision history:

```
Disallow: /posts/
Disallow: /posts?
```

Since the revision history is located at `/posts/{{id}}/revisions`, it should not be indexed. If a search engine *is* indexing it, there's nothing we can do about that.